# React Native renders previous page before going to the intended screen

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

New to react native so I'm not sure if this is just a glitch. My ultimate intention is to check if a user has been fully onboarded or not. If a user logs in, they're a returning user, so they shouldn't go through the onboarding screens again.

This is the flow:
New user? Landing -> Registration -> Onboarding -> Home

Existing user? Landing -> Login -> Home

In order to know if the user is a returning user, I check to see if the onboarded completed variable is in the firestore db and if it's true, the Onboarded function is set to true. This all works fine, except that before the login page switches to the home page upon login, the screen displays the onboarding page for a quick second. How do I stop this? As this isn't ideal in production.

Here is a snippet of the login

```
export function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { onboarded, setOnboarded, login } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const userCred = await login(email, password);
    const docRef = doc(db, "userInfo", userCred.user.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      if (docSnap.get("onboardingCompleted") === true) {
        setOnboarded(true);
      } else {
        console.log("nothing here for you");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("nothing exists!");
    }
  };
```

Here is a snippet of my Routes page:

```
const Routes = () => {
  const { user, setUser, onboarded, setOnboarded } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);

  const StateChanged = (user) => {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, StateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);
 
  if (initializing) return null;

  const DisplayStacks = () => {
    if (user && onboarded) {
      // returning user or end of onboarding; working for returning user
      return <AppStack />;
    } else if (user) {
      //after registering; clicking create account; working fine
      return <RegistrationStack />;
    } else {
      return <AuthStack />; // before registering; working fine
    }
  };
  return <NavigationContainer>{DisplayStacks()}</NavigationContainer>;
};

export default Routes;
```

Auth Context:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [onboarded, setOnboarded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        onboarded,
        setOnboarded,

        login: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            const res = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            return res;
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            alert("Wrong info mane!!");
          }
        },
        register: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            alert(e);
          }
        },
        logout: async () => {
          try {
            await signOut(auth);
            setOnboarded(false);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

User state is created in the Auth context, but it's set in the routes page

Comment: Maybe don't set `initializing` state to `false` until you've confirmed the onboarding status.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: It seems that whether or not a user has onboarded yet is an important detail and perhaps the code shouldn't set that the user is initialized until the onboarding check is completed. I may have a suggestion but would like to see more of the code, specifically the `AuthContext` and provider, the `login` function, and where/how the `user` state is set. Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Centralize the authentication logic and the logic to check if an authenticated user has been onboarded into the `AuthProvider` component. In the `stateChange` callback for the `onAuthStateChanged` event handler do an additional `isOnboarded` check, and then only after both the `user` *and* `isOnboarded` states/checks have completed is the `initializing` state set `false`. This is obviously all not tested but I believe should get you close to the UX you desire.

AuthProvider

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isOnboarded, setIsOnboarded] = useState(false);
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkOnboardStatus = async (userId) => {
      const docRef = doc(db, "userInfo", userId);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        return docSnap.get("onboardingCompleted");
      } else {
        console.log("nothing exists!");
      }
    };
  
    const stateChanged = async (user) => {
      setUser(user);
      try {
        if (user?.uid) {
          // have a user, check isOnboarded status
          const isOnboarded = await checkOnboardStatus();
          if (!isOnboarded) {
            console.log("nothing here for you");
          }
          setIsOnboarded(isOnboarded);
        } else {
          // no user, clear isOnboarded status
          setIsOnboarded(false);
        }
      } catch(error) {
        // handle any fetching/processing error if necessary
      } finally {
        setInitializing(false);
      }
    };

    const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, stateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  const login = (email, password) => {
    try {
      // Set initializing true here each time a user is authenticating
      // to make the UI wait for the onboarded check to complete
      setInitializing(true);

      return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert("Wrong info mane!!");
    }
  };

  const register = (email, password) => {
    try {
      return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert(e);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    try {
      return signOut(auth);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        isOnboarded,
        initializing,
        login,
        register,
        logout,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Routes

```
const Routes = () => {
  const { user, isOnboarded, initializing } = useContext(AuthContext);
 
  if (initializing) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user
        ? isOnboarded ? <AppStack /> : <RegistrationStack />
        : <AuthStack />
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  );

};
```

LoginScreen

```
export function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { login } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = () => {
    login(email, password);
  };

  ...
```

[image: Edit react-native-renders-previous-page-before-going-to-the-intended-screen]

Comment: This is really nice thanks! Made some tweaks to this and it returns the same thing my previous components were returning. The problem is persisting unfortunately.

Comment: @davidocodes I'm curious what *your* reproduction steps are. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-renders-previous-page-before-going-to-the-intended-screen-5fp42p) demo that handles initializing the user and onboarding state as you describe, with no "leaking" of the registration/onboarding page prior to rendering the `AppStack`. ***Now*** what I ***do*** see after the initial mounting of the app and relogging the user the initialization has already occurred, so this additional check is skipped and the `registration/onboarding page` is momentarily rendered.

Comment: @davidocodes I've tried to mock the firebase code/logic as closely as possible. Can you take a look at the linked sandbox and confirm (1) if the reproductions steps I've described are accurate, and (2) this is equivalent to what you are seeing on your end? If it's inaccurate then please provide your exact reproduction steps. Please also clarify what the expected behavior should be ***after*** the has mounted and been initialized. Perhaps you want the initialization step each time a user authenticates?

Comment: @davidocodes Actually, I think my reproduction steps are fairly accurate. I've applied a change to the sandbox that triggers "initializing" each time a user is authenticating or the app is mounting.